# How to make Jqplot-cursor respond to 'touchmove' event in touch-phone using jqplot library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot, jquery-events

`Jqplot cursor` works fine in a desktop. It follows the mouse, but I want to make it follow the virtual mouse in phone. The event for this would be `vmouseover`. Jqplot cursor by default doesn't seem to follow mouse (i.e. touch(not tap)) in android. Is there any way I can override the the event to which cursor responds so that I can get it working in android. Currently I am redrawing the whole plot on `vmouseover` event but that is way too CPU-expensive. I want the plots to behave like the plots in applications for stocks (refer pic below)

[image]

Below is my code. Pardon any syntax-error.

```
   $(document).delegate("div[data-role*='page']", "pageshow", function () {

     $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
     var plot1;

     $(window).on('orientationchange', function (event) {
            console.log(orientation);

             $('#chartdiv').empty();
             setTimeout(function ()
             {
                 plot1.replot({ resetAxes: true });
             }, 200);
     });

     var s11 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
     var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
     var s2 = [];
     var s3 = [260, 440, 320, 200];

     legendLabels = ['Load/Unload', 'Cycle'];

     var options = {
         //Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
         //animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,

         seriesDefaults:
             {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                 rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
             },

         series: [
           {label:'Timing',renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer, },
           { label: 'CrossHair', renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer, color: 'red', },
           { label: 'CrossHair', renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer, color: 'red', }
         ],

         cursor: {
             showTooltip: true,
             tooltipLocation: 'sw',
             followMouse: true,
             zoom: true
         },

         legend: {
             renderer: $.jqplot.MekkoLegendRenderer,
             show: true,
             location: 'n',
             labels: legendLabels,
             rendererOptions:
             {                    
                 numberRows: 1,
                 placement: "outside"
             },
             marginTop: "30px"
         },

         axes: {
             // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
             xaxis: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                 ticks: ticks
             },
             // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
             // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
             yaxis: {
                 pad: 1.05,
                 tickOptions: { formatString: '$%d' }
             }           
         },           
     };

     plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2, s3], options);

        $('#chartdiv').bind('vmousemove', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data, radius) {
             $('.jqplot-event-canvas').css('cursor', 'pointer');

             var loc = new Array;
             loc.push([((ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth) * plot1.axes.xaxis.max,
                        ((ev.pageY - this.offsetTop) / this.offsetHeight)*plot1.axes.yaxis.max]);
             console.log(loc[0]);

             plot1.destroy();
             plot1 = $.jqplot("chartdiv", [s1, [[((ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth) * plot1.axes.xaxis.max,0],
                 [((ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth) * plot1.axes.xaxis.max, 1100]]], options);

         });
```

Comment: please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have shared the code. anonymous method in 'vmouseover' event is just an indicative. Its not working as I expected it to. Even if it does it will be very CPU-expensive.

Comment: Oh I was searching for the same! @BhushanKawadkar did you find any sol.?